# How to get all the matches from a file based on names in another file?

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, files, join

I have a file named `file1` with information like below:

```
TCONS_00000011  XLOC_000003     -       u       q1:MSTRG.39|MSTRG.39.9|4|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|7468
TCONS_00000012  XLOC_000004     -       u       q1:MSTRG.41|MSTRG.41.1|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|1270
TCONS_00000013  XLOC_000003     -       u       q1:MSTRG.39|MSTRG.39.10|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|6835
TCONS_00000014  XLOC_000003     -       u       q1:MSTRG.39|MSTRG.39.11|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|880
TCONS_00000015  XLOC_000003     -       u       q1:MSTRG.39|MSTRG.39.12|3|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|377
TCONS_00000016  XLOC_000005     -       u       q1:MSTRG.2|MSTRG.2.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|709
TCONS_00000017  XLOC_000006     -       u       q1:MSTRG.4|MSTRG.4.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|343
TCONS_00000018  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.1|7|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|12112
TCONS_00000019  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.2|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|310
TCONS_00000020  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.3|3|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|538
TCONS_00000021  XLOC_000008     -       u       q1:MSTRG.42|MSTRG.42.1|9|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|6331
TCONS_00000022  XLOC_000008     -       u       q1:MSTRG.42|MSTRG.42.2|5|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|1311
TCONS_00000023  XLOC_000008     -       u       q1:MSTRG.42|MSTRG.42.3|5|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|923
TCONS_00000024  XLOC_000008     -       u       q1:MSTRG.42|MSTRG.42.4|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|455
TCONS_00000025  XLOC_000009     -       u       q1:MSTRG.7|MSTRG.7.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|232
TCONS_00000026  XLOC_000010     -       u       q1:MSTRG.6|MSTRG.6.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|483
TCONS_00000027  XLOC_000011     -       u       q1:MSTRG.12|MSTRG.12.1|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|2489
TCONS_00000028  XLOC_000012     -       u       q1:MSTRG.14|MSTRG.14.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|7604
TCONS_00000029  XLOC_000013     -       u       q1:MSTRG.55|MSTRG.55.1|4|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|1511
```

And `file2` is like below:

```
XLOC_000005
XLOC_000007
XLOC_000009
XLOC_000010
XLOC_000012
```

Based on information from `file2` if it matches with second column in `file1` I want to extract all information from `file1`. And the output should look like below:

```
TCONS_00000016  XLOC_000005     -       u       q1:MSTRG.2|MSTRG.2.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|709
TCONS_00000018  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.1|7|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|12112
TCONS_00000019  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.2|2|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|310
TCONS_00000020  XLOC_000007     -       u       q1:MSTRG.40|MSTRG.40.3|3|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|538
TCONS_00000025  XLOC_000009     -       u       q1:MSTRG.7|MSTRG.7.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|232
TCONS_00000026  XLOC_000010     -       u       q1:MSTRG.6|MSTRG.6.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|483
TCONS_00000028  XLOC_000012     -       u       q1:MSTRG.14|MSTRG.14.1|1|0.000000|0.000000|0.000000|7604
```

How can I do this linux?

Comment: @Quasímodo that's not a solution because it doesn't address partial matches and matches on a specific field.

Comment: @EdMorton The `-w` flag of Grep covers partial matches. It does not address field matches, but as far as the sample is concerned, it is a solution.

Comment: @Quasímodo best I can see none of the answers there mention `-w`.

Comment: @EdMorton Very true, it is not even a POSIX flag. But applying a simple `grep -f file2 file1` solves the problem at hand, where `XLOC_...` being present in any other field is out of the structure of the file, as well as partial matches.

Comment: yes I actually tried this `grep -w -f file2 file1` but didn't work

Comment: Maven, it is a nice thing to mention your attempts in the question. It shows you have given the problem your try and it avoids contributors pointing ways that you know that fail. `grep -w -f file2 file1` works perfectly for me with your sample input. Your problem is solved now, but for your future question, bear in mind "doesn't work" is not an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' file2 file1
```